# Laptop dies when AC unplugged

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I changed my battery, it worked for a day, then stopped doing so overnight.
Ubuntu says the laptop is fully charged, but when I unplug it from the wall it dies. My old battery works fine. What should I try?

- **My laptop:** Lenovo T410
- **Battery led status indicator:** blinking orange, not sure if "fast" or "quick". [Meaning](http://manualmachine.com/lenovo/thinkpad-t410-t410i/205425-service-manual/page:13/):

  > Fast blinking orange: The battery has less than 5% charge. Note: The
  >   battery may be charging.   Quick blinking orange: An error has been
  >   occurred in the battery.
- Some info Ubuntu gives me. I noted with "old" when the old battery is inside.

  ```
  ~$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

  native-path:         BAT0
  vendor:              SANYO (old: LGC)
  model:               42T4791 (old: 42T4911)
  power supply:        yes
  has history:         yes
  has statistics:      yes
  battery present:     yes  
  rechargeable:        yes  
  state:               fully-charged  
  warning-level:       none  
  energy:              84.0996 Wh (old: 13.5324 Wh)  
  energy-empty:        0 Wh  
  energy-full:         84.0996 Wh (old: 14.202 Wh)  
  energy-full-design:  84.24 Wh (old: 47.52 Wh)  
  energy-rate:         0 W  
  voltage:             12.492 V (old: 12.055 V)  
  percentage:          100%  
  capacity:            99.8333% (old: 29.8864%)  
  technology:          lithium-ion  
  icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
  ```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/828789/my-asus-laptop-shuts-down-unexpectedly-when-unplugged?rq=1 check the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the battery no charger. If it doesnt work hold down the power button for 30 seconds. Pull the battery for say, 30 more (just to be safe) reinsert the battery and try both ways again. Most laptops also have a reset button. Most of the time in the front. Its a pin hole big enough for a straightened paper clip. You can try pushing that for 10 seconds, try it all again.

Comment: Nothing changes.